# Math.floor(Math.random()) what does +1 actually do?

Tags: javascript

When you have `Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1` its supposed to pick a random number between 1-10 from what I understand.

However, when I change the `+1` to any number higher or lower then `1` I get the same result. Why is this? What does the `+1` mean exactly?

Comment: If you add something more than `+1` and you still end up with numbers between 1-10 something is very wrong.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "same result"? can you clarify or post some output?

Comment: (To clarify--if you *always* and *only* get numbers between 1-10. Obviously any given run might only produce 1-10, but over time, this will almost certainly *not* be the case.)

Comment: *"when I change the +1... I get the same result."* This question is based on a false premise. I think you know what adding `1` does, but you have some other issue in your code. If you have such an issue, please post your actual code.

Comment: @DaveNewton: http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/

Comment: With the exception of Salman A, you guys aren't helpful at all nor understood that it was a concept question. Moving forward, if you see a question from me, don't bother replying especially you "am not i am" as it was just announced today that you won the trolling trophy for "least helpful but most condescending" Thank you tadman below for answering with proper insight and not patronizing "the new guy" hopefully more people are as bright as you.

Comment: @user1485897 You explicitly asked what "+1" meant, and claimed it made no difference; what other conclusion beyond believing you're incorrect, or something is horribly wrong, can we draw? You were asked for your specific code by "the troll", which is the appropriate response.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The random number generator produces a value in the range of 0.0 <= n < 1.0. If you want a number between 1 and something you'll need to apply a `+1` offset.

Generally you can use:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * N) + M
```

This will generate values between M and M + N - 1.

**[demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dLL8P/1/)**

Comment: not entirely true: due to `Math.floor` its between M and M+N-1. You need `Math.round` to have numbers between M and M+N. However, in that case the distrubution is not equal, as M and M+N only have half the chance to roll.

Comment: You're correct. By "between" I mean "up to but not including", which is technically values in the M <= n < M+N range.

Comment: @Christoph Just found walked in on this post from Google, it wasn't until I read your comment that I FULLY understood how `Math.floor((Math.random() * N) + M)` worked. So, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`Math.random()` generates a random number between 0 and 1.

Therefore `Math.random()*10` generates a random number between 0 and 10, and `(Math.random()*10)+1` a number between 1 and 11.

`Math.floor()` drops the decimal of this number, and makes it an integer from 0 to 10.

You can see a sequential progression of the logic [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wwnTr/)

Comment: `Math.random()` can also generate `0.9999...`. To be exact, `Math.random()` generates a number between (including) 0 and (excluding) 1.

Comment: To verify, I ran `Math.random()` four times. It does not only clearly show that a float above `0.9` can be obtained, but also that you can [never be sure about randomness](http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/): 0.9491507810734872 / 
0.9815085749153463 / 
0.7040373403047864 / 
0.9940599762680827

Comment: Good point - updated answer accordingly. And yes, but is anything ever truly "random"!

Comment: 0.9940599762680827 is a float above 0.9, no?

Comment: @jacktheripper Depends on your definition and whether or not you can predict the outcome of quantum mechanics.

Comment: @SalmanA Uh... yes, it is. I'm not sure I understand your point, though.

Comment: @jacktheripper Correct. So yes, things *can* be truly random.

Answer (score 3):

Whole number is between 1 and 10

- **Math.random()** generates number between 0 and 1 (with many decimal places).

etc: 
math.random()  [randomly return : 0.19157057767733932]
(*this number will still have many decimal places*)

To get a random whole number, you need to multiply random generated number by 10.

etc 
math.random()*10 =[randomly return : 2.9757621488533914]

- Since the number will still have many decimal places, use **floor() method** to round a number down/nearest integer, this will give u a value between 0 and 9. Then, u can add 1 to make it a number between 1 and 10.

etc:
math.floor(0.6)         [return 0 ] 
math.floor(0.6)+ 1       [return 1]

Answer (score 0):

Basic:

`(random() >= 0)` always `true`

`(random() < 1)` always `true`

`(Math.floor(random()) == 0)` always `true`

Maximum:

`(Math.floor(random() * 10) >= 0)` always `true`

`(Math.floor(random() * 10) < 10)` always `true`

Minimum:

`(Math.floor(random() * 10) + 1 >= 1)` always `true`

`(Math.floor(random() * 10) + 1 < 11)` always `true`

Max Round:

`(Math.round(random() * 10, 0) >= 0)` always `true`

`(Math.round(random() * 10, 0) <= 10)` always `true`